# Atualizar dados de Tabela MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Não consigo realizar *UPDATE* dos dados de minha tabela.

```
$id = 7;
$TrocaNome = "Ronaldo";  
$TrocaEmail = "Ronaldo@ronaldo.com";  
$up = "UPDATE usuario SET nome='$TrocaNome', email='$TrocaEmail' WHERE id=$id";  
 var_dump($id,$TrocaNome,$TrocaEmail);  **//verifica se esta recebendo informações  
 passadas.**
```

---

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) < 1){  
echo "Nenhuma informação foi registrada no sistema.";  
}else{  
    echo"Dados Atualizados copm Sucesso";  
}  
mysqli_close($conn);
```

RESULTADO:  `int(7)` Nenhuma informação foi registrada no sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando executar sua *query*:

```
$id = 7;
$TrocaNome = "Ronaldo";  
$TrocaEmail = "Ronaldo@ronaldo.com";  
$up = "UPDATE usuario SET nome='$TrocaNome', email='$TrocaEmail' WHERE id=$id";  
$exec = mysqli_query($conn, $up);
```

---

#### Links úteis

Documentação: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)